# Can you find out if a Django Model instance is "dirty"?

Tags: django, orm, sqlalchemy

I really like the feature of SQLAlchemy that allows you to see if an object is dirty: if it has been modified since it was retrieved from the database, or the last time it was saved.

Is it possible to find this information from the Django ORM?

Note this is not the same as [Dirty fields in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110803/dirty-fields-in-django), as I don't care about what the previous data was, although S.Lott's answer may provide a way to do it, but I would like a way that doesn't hit the database.

I have also looked at the `django.db.transaction.is_dirty()`, but this doesn't seem to be the solution.

Comment: the question is not so different and the same answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110803/dirty-fields-in-django may work for your problem

Comment: this is the same kind of answer as http://stackoverflow.com/a/332225/1733117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that does do a database query:

```
class DirtyMixin(object):
    @property
    def is_dirty(self):
        db_obj = self.__class__.objects.get(self.pk)
        for f in self._meta.local_fields:
            if self.__getattribute__(f.name) != db_obj.__getattribute__(f.name):
                return True
        return False
```

You can then add this as an ancestor class to a model.  Or, monkey-patch the forms.Model class, if you like.

```
from django.db import models
models.Model.__bases__ = (DirtyMixin,) + models.Model.__bases__
```

Comment: Won't this throw an exception if the model hasn't been saved yet? Seems like that should be caught and `True` returned.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably an oversight.

Comment: AttributeError: 'MyObject' object has no attribute 'get'.  Don't you mean something like self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)?

Comment: @Julian quite probably.

Comment: `getattr(self, f.name)` rather than the dunder methods would probably be cleaner...

Answer (score 2):

Another way, involving overriding `__setattr__`, is discussed at some length in [this Django ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4102).

Comment: This is a good answer but would be better if it included code not just a link.

Answer (score 1):

try use [lck.django](https://github.com/ambv/kitdjango) class [TimeTrackable](http://packages.python.org/lck.django/lck.django.common.models.html#lck.django.common.models.TimeTrackable)

Comment: Nice. That looks like a powerful way to do it.