# Capture all fields that have changed in a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-reversion

What I'm trying to do is get a record of all the fields that may have changed after a object has changed. I know there are many ways to tell if an object has changed as well as some other django packages like [django-revisions](http://stdbrouw.github.com/django-revisions/), [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion), and [django-simple-history](https://bitbucket.org/q/django-simple-history/) but I want to be able to have a report that shows all of the field that have changed, not just one. I also what to show what the field was before it was changed so I can have a complete audit on the object.

I was thinking of adding a json field with [django-jsonfield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield/0.9.2) but felt kind of wrong to do it like this. As if it was a hack or dirty work around. Is there a more traditional or simpler way to do this.

Comment: this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110803/dirty-fields-in-django and to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141484/can-you-find-out-if-a-django-model-instance-is-dirty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might take a look at [django-dirtyfields](https://github.com/smn/django-dirtyfields). When an object is updated, you could get a list of all of the fields that are dirty and generate the report you need. It won't do this automatically, but it would get you the fields that have been changed.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Nice and light weight and very easy to implement. Have already started making my reports. Thank you!