# Actions triggered by field change in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do I have actions occur when a field gets changed in one of my models?  In this particular case, I have this model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        ('S', 'Setup'),
        ('A', 'Active'),
        ('P', 'Paused'),
        ('F', 'Finished')
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    started = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default='S')
```

and I would like to have Units created, and the 'started' field populated with the current datetime (among other things), when the state goes from Setup to Active.

I suspect that a model instance method is needed, but the docs don't seem to have much to say about using them in this manner.

**Update:** I've added the following to my Game class:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.old_state = self.state

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        if self.old_state == 'S' and self.state == 'A':
            self.started = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(Game, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
        self.old_state = self.state
```

Comment: I've updated my answer in line with your comment.

Comment: django-model-utils implements a monitor field useful for your started field case: https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#monitorfield

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically, you need to override the `save` method, check if the `state` field was changed, set `started` if needed and then let the model base class finish persisting to the database.

The tricky part is figuring out if the field was changed.  Check out the mixins and other solutions in this question to help you out with this:

- [Dirty fields in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110803/dirty-fields-in-django)

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about overriding methods in Django's ORM. IMO, this would be better accomplished using django.db.models.signals.post_save.

Comment: @cpharmston: I think this is acceptable: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods -- I use signals when an entity other than the model wants to be notified, but in this case the entity is the model itself, so just override save (this is fairly conventional with object oriented methods).

Comment: Overriding save() did not work on bulk admin operations the last time I tried (1.0 I think)

Comment: Using signals seems to me to be more elegant, but in this case it does appear that overriding save() is the expected thing.

Comment: FWIW neither `save` nor signals will be called when doing bulk updates. See the note below the example at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update

Answer (score 46):

It has been answered, but here's an example of using signals, post_init and post_save.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_init

class MyModel(models.Model):
    state = models.IntegerField()
    previous_state = None

    @staticmethod
    def post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if instance.previous_state != instance.state or created:
            do_something_with_state_change()

    @staticmethod
    def remember_state(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.previous_state = instance.state

post_save.connect(MyModel.post_save, sender=MyModel)
post_init.connect(MyModel.remember_state, sender=MyModel)
```

Comment: For those still looking for a solution to the above problem, this worked like a charm for me. Only edit is that I had to import the post_save and post_init functions at the beginning of my models.py: `from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_init`

Comment: It seem a little late for the party,I achieved the expected results using the above code，but when I query the object with "only" in ORM, like `MyModel.objects.only('id')` .it raise RecursionError, I guess it caused by post_init.

Comment: It is known that this issue will occur in django<=2.2 and may have been fixed in later version.

Answer (score 20):

Django has a nifty feature called [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/), which are effectively triggers that are set off at specific times:

- Before/after a model's save method is called
- Before/after a model's delete method is called
- Before/after an HTTP request is made

Read the docs for full info, but all you need to do is create a receiver function and register it as a signal. This is usually done in models.py.

```
from django.core.signals import request_finished

def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print "Request finished!"

request_finished.connect(my_callback)
```

Simple, eh?

Answer (score 9):

One way is to add a setter for the state. It's just a normal method, nothing special.

```
class Game(models.Model):
   # ... other code

    def set_state(self, newstate):
        if self.state != newstate:
            oldstate = self.state
            self.state = newstate
            if oldstate == 'S' and newstate == 'A':
                self.started = datetime.now()
                # create units, etc.
```

**Update:** If you want this to be triggered *whenever* a change is made to a model instance, you can (*instead* of `set_state` above) use a `__setattr__` method in `Game` which is something like this:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name != "state":
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
    else:
        if self.state != value:
            oldstate = self.state
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value) # use base class setter
            if oldstate == 'S' and value == 'A':
                self.started = datetime.now()
                # create units, etc.
```

Note that you wouldn't especially find this in the Django docs, as it (`__setattr__`) is a standard Python feature, documented [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__setattr__#object.__setattr__), and is not Django-specific.

note: Don't know about versions of django older than 1.2, but this code using `__setattr__` won't work, it'll fail just after the second `if`, when trying to access `self.state`.

I tried something similar, and I tried to fix this problem by forcing the initialization of `state` (first in `__init__` then ) in `__new__` but this will lead to nasty unexpected behaviour.

I'm editing instead of commenting for obvious reasons, also: I'm not deleting this piece of code since maybe it could work with older (or future?) versions of django, and there may be another workaround to the `self.state` problem that i'm unaware of

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't clear to me how to make such a method be used whenever editing, say, from the admin page.

Answer (score 5):

@dcramer came up with a more elegant solution (in my opinion) for this issue.

https://gist.github.com/730765

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_init

def track_data(*fields):
    """
    Tracks property changes on a model instance.

    The changed list of properties is refreshed on model initialization
    and save.

    >>> @track_data('name')
    >>> class Post(models.Model):
    >>>     name = models.CharField(...)
    >>> 
    >>>     @classmethod
    >>>     def post_save(cls, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    >>>         if instance.has_changed('name'):
    >>>             print "Hooray!"
    """

    UNSAVED = dict()

    def _store(self):
        "Updates a local copy of attributes values"
        if self.id:
            self.__data = dict((f, getattr(self, f)) for f in fields)
        else:
            self.__data = UNSAVED

    def inner(cls):
        # contains a local copy of the previous values of attributes
        cls.__data = {}

        def has_changed(self, field):
            "Returns ``True`` if ``field`` has changed since initialization."
            if self.__data is UNSAVED:
                return False
            return self.__data.get(field) != getattr(self, field)
        cls.has_changed = has_changed

        def old_value(self, field):
            "Returns the previous value of ``field``"
            return self.__data.get(field)
        cls.old_value = old_value

        def whats_changed(self):
            "Returns a list of changed attributes."
            changed = {}
            if self.__data is UNSAVED:
                return changed
            for k, v in self.__data.iteritems():
                if v != getattr(self, k):
                    changed[k] = v
            return changed
        cls.whats_changed = whats_changed

        # Ensure we are updating local attributes on model init
        def _post_init(sender, instance, **kwargs):
            _store(instance)
        post_init.connect(_post_init, sender=cls, weak=False)

        # Ensure we are updating local attributes on model save
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            save._original(self, *args, **kwargs)
            _store(self)
        save._original = cls.save
        cls.save = save
        return cls
    return inner
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to put the following code to app's `__init__.py`:

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(signals.pre_save)
def models_pre_save(sender, instance, **_):
    if not sender.__module__.startswith('myproj.myapp.models'):
        # ignore models of other apps
        return

    if instance.pk:
        old = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        fields = sender._meta.local_fields

        for field in fields:
            try:
                func = getattr(sender, field.name + '_changed', None)  # class function or static function
                if func and callable(func) and getattr(old, field.name, None) != getattr(instance, field.name, None):
                    # field has changed
                    func(old, instance)
            except:
                pass
```

and add `<field_name>_changed` static method to my model class:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Product|sold'))
    sold_dt = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Product|sold datetime'))

    @staticmethod
    def sold_changed(old_obj, new_obj):
        if new_obj.sold is True:
            new_obj.sold_dt = timezone.now()
        else:
            new_obj.sold_dt = None
```

then the `sold_dt` field will change when `sold` field changes.

Any changes of any field defined in the model will trigger the `<field_name>_changed` method, with old and new object as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Dirty to detect changes and over-writing save method**
[dirty field](https://github.com/romgar/django-dirtyfields)

*My prev ans: [Actions triggered by field change in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197674/actions-triggered-by-field-change-in-django)*

```
class Game(DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        ('S', 'Setup'),
        ('A', 'Active'),
        ('P', 'Paused'),
        ('F', 'Finished')
        )
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default='S')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_dirty():
            dirty_fields = self.get_dirty_fields()
            if 'state' in dirty_fields:
                Do_some_action()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PostgreSQL you can create a trigger:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON accounts
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.balance IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.balance)
    EXECUTE FUNCTION check_account_update();
```