# Get information from related object in generic list view

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

So, I've been noodling about with Django's generic views, specifically the `object_list` view.  I have this in my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import list_detail
from diplomacy.engine.models import Game

game_info = {
    "queryset": Game.objects.filter(state__in=('A', 'P')),
    "template_object_name": "game",
    }

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', list_detail.object_list, game_info),
)
```

and this fairly rough template that it is going to:

```
{% block content %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Turn</th>
      <th>Last Generated</th>
    </tr>
    {% for game in game_list %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ game.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

What I'm looking for is the best idiomatic way of including in this view the unicode representation and `generated` field (a `DateTimeField`) from the *most recent* `Turn` that points to the current `Game` in the loop, based on the value of `generated`.  `Turn.game` is the field that points to the `Game` the turn belongs to (a `ForeignKey`).

**Update:**

My `Turn` model is as follows:

```
SEASON_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Spring'),
    ('SR', 'Spring Retreat'),
    ('F', 'Fall'),
    ('FR', 'Fall Retreat'),
    ('FB', 'Fall Build')
    )

class Turn(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    season = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SEASON_CHOICES)
    generated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.season, self.year)
```

The `Game` model has not appreciably changed from the way I specified it in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197674/actions-triggered-by-field-change-in-django).

Comment: can you post the model you're referring to?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Turn.game` points to the associated `Game` object, then `{{game.turn_set.all}}` should return the set of `Turn` objects for that game.

You may need to add a Meta class to the `Turn` model to order from newest to oldest.

```
Class Meta:
    ordering = ['-generated']
```

Then, `{{game.turn_set.all.0}}` should return the unicode representation for the newest turn for that game, and `{{game.turn_set.all.0.generated}}` will return the associated `datetime` object.

Note: This is untested code.

Comment: This, by itself, is insufficient.  I can see the newly added <td></td>  tags, but they do not have anything between them.