# Perform action upon django model status modification

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I've been stucked on this problem for a few days. How can I perform a specific action when an object's status has been updated?

I'v got an `Order` django model with a `status` field. When an order's status goes from `new` to `processed`, I need to perform some specific actions.

The thing is, the status can be updated from anywhere: a frontend view, an admin module, a bulk action, a management command, etc.

Also, I only want the action to be performed after the order is saved.

It seems the `post_save` signal could work, but I cannot find a way to detect if the status has changed, and what the old value is.

I checked the [django fsm, but it's clearly not the way to go](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm/issues/9).

Any idea?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://github.com/Atomidata/django-audit-log ?

Comment: Seems a bit overkill. Plus « …it can only track changes to model instances when they are made via the web interface of your application. »

Answer (score 1):

To detect which fields have changed in the `post_save` signal, you somehow need to remember the original state of the model instance. One answer to [Actions triggered by field change in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197674/actions-triggered-by-field-change-in-django) is considering this and points to [Dirty fields in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110803/dirty-fields-in-django), where you can find various mix-ins that will allow you to find the "dirty" fields in your model when saving.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I understand, there is not instance created in the case of a bulk update, hence the dirty fields strategy won't work, right?

Comment: That's true, `update` doesn't call `save` nor trigger signals (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once). You could either overwrite `update` in a custom manager to do what you want, or handle updates with SQL directly, e.g. triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html (not involving Django/Python at all).