# How to check for a specific field change in a model?

Tags: python, django, orm, signals, django-signals

I have my `models.py` :

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)


class Currency(models.Mode):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Whenever the `currency` field in hotel is changing I need to be able to do something. So I have a function like :

```
@receiver(pre_save,sender=Hotel)
def update_something(sender,**kwargs)
    obj = kwargs['instance']
    old_object = Hotel.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
    '''
     Now I can do anything here comparing the oldo  object with the instance
    '''
```

The thing is I don't want to make a query for this, since then the purpose of signals becomes stupid and I become a fool.

So I should be able to do something like :

```
updated = kwargs['update_fields']
new_currency = updated['currency']
```

Is their a way I can find out that change for *ONLY* one particular field say `currency` ,instead of doing a query like this. I want to get the changes related to the `currency` foreign key and update things before I save.

Sorry for my bad English and not being able to use too technical terms.

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you will find everything you need there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197674/actions-triggered-by-field-change-in-django. You can either use the __init__ and __save__ methods together with overriding them, or override the __setter__ !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: When saving, how can you check if a field has changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather hacky solution is to save object state on initialization.

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class Currency(models.Mode):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Currency, self).__init__()
        self.__state = model_to_dict(self)

    def updated(self):
        new_state = model_to_dict(self)
        return dict(set(self.__state.iteritems()) - set(new_state.iteritems()))
```

Method `updated` will return difference between initial and new states.

Answer (score 2):

The point of signals is better decoupling - allow other applications (that you don't necessarily know yet) to transparently hook into your application and/or avoid circular dependencies between application. There's really no point in using a signal here afaik (unless of course the signal handler is in another app and you don't want the app with the `Hotel` and `Currency` models to depend on this other app).

To answer your question: doing a query to retrieve the original state is the only way you can compare stored value and current value. Now if you're only interested in one specific field, you of course don't have to retrieve the whole model instance - just use `queryset.values_list`:

```
old_currency = Hotel.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).values_list("currency", flat=True)[0]
```