# How do I rollback changes to unsaved model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.5

Scenario: I have a model which I've made changes too, but the model is not yet saved. Then, my software might decide to reject those changes. I'd like to restore the model to it's original non-dirty state. Of course, I could re-query the model from the database, but I'd like to avoid that. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Take a look:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110803/dirty-fields-in-django

Comment: Thanks Alex for the link.