# Does django know what fields were updated?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm trying to find out how django's save() works. And there is some thing I can't understand. Is there any way to know what field is updating at the moment?

The best way I know is use pre_save() signal and do smth like this:

```
current_field_val = instance.my_field
old_field_val == sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).my_field
if current_field_val != old_field_val:
    # do smth
```

But I don't want to select from DB. And how DjangoORM knows what field needs to be updated, or it updates all fields in the model(it seems to me it's strange behaviour).

Comment: https://github.com/smn/django-dirtyfields

Comment: there is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110803/dirty-fields-in-django

Answer (score 1):

In a view, you can use `form.changed_data` to find out which data is changed in the form.

E.g.

```
if 'yourfield' in form.changed_data`:
    (do something)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. It's better. Thanks. But it doesn't cover all needs sometimes. As Hasan Ramezani said - 'it is a good idea for contribution in django' :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
class myClass(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField()

    __my_field_orig = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__my_field_orig = self.my_field

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.my_field != self.__my_field_orig:
            # my_field changed - do something here

        super(myClass, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_name = self.name
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this way too, I just want to find default solution. For example RoR orm allows this:

    `recod.title = "someothertitle"`
    `record.changes`

    `{"title"=>["sometitle", "someothertitle"]}`


And also I want to know how Django acts. Is it updates all fields or it keeps somewhere fields to change..? And if it acts in the second way - why Django doesn't want to give to me that info :)

Comment: @VladimirSolovyov yes dude your right :). it is a good idea for contribution in django :))